# X-UA-Compatible IE=10 not working on EDGE

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, x-ua-compatible

I am using a library not compatible with EDGE so i am trying to change the Document mode to IE10. I have applied

```
httpReponse.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=10");
```

Its working for all but In Edge its still not working. Document Mode is still Edge in Edge browser. Please suggest if i am missing anything.

Comment: According to [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-iedoco/d3fffb13-31cc-4dd0-b38c-2b6aaabc153e), Edge doesn't support any IE document modes (other than its own).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. It will really help. Just to confirm like is this relates to any specific version of Edge coz as far as i know before 4-5 months this was working fine but not Now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article [X-UA-Compatibility Meta Tag and HTTP Response Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-iedoco/380e2488-f5eb-4457-a07a-0cb1b6e4b4b5)

The X-UA-Compatibility Meta Tag and HTTP Response Header will not be implemented in any version of Microsoft Edge.